# Which microservice library is best or mostly used?

Tags: microservices

I am split my business logic into micro services. Which micro services library is good or mostly used? what about apache karaf?

Comment: What do you mean by **micro services library** ?

Comment: @Trung I think by "library" the OP means framework or platform.

Comment: Sorry. Which framework is mostly used for developing microservices?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Karaf is an OSGI container. OSGI with its modularity is an appealing solution to microservices. OSGI however can be quite complex with a steep learning curve. A better OSGI use case might be a plugin system / application.

[Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) is a great option. The benefit of Spring Boot would be all the additional features you get to manage your microservices once deployed, i.e. the actuator project for monitoring and [Spring Cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) which provide features such routing, load balancing, configuration, distributed messaging, etc. They have done all the legwork for you to get your microservices into production as quickly as possibly.

You can also look at [Wildfly Swarm](http://wildfly-swarm.io/) if you prefer plain JEE over Spring.

[Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/) is also a good option.

These only scratch the surface, but are a great starting point.